# Integrate twitter in drupal 7 website

Tags: drupal, twitter, oauth

I am trying to get the twitter module (7.x-5.4) running on my local drupal 7.19 website. Already installed Oauth and registered a twitter app. I am using the keys of that twitter app.

Callback URL
`http://localhost/drupal-7.19/twitter/oauth`

twitter host
http://twitter.com

Twitter API
https://api.twitter.com

Twitter search
http://search.twitter.com

TinyURL
http://tinyurl.com

when I want to add at least my own twitter account so that the site can display my tweets. when I want to add this account, an error occurs:

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in Twitter->request() (line 131 of root\modules\twitter\twitter.lib.php).
Could not obtain a valid token from the Twitter API. Please review the configuration.

any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: since the error says please review your configuration, maybe you could post it here?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, uncommenting the line 
    extension=php_openssl.dll 
in php.ini resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work for you, but this worked for me. I had the same exact error, even though I had followed the documentation. Here's the test: go to admin/reports/status. If you see the following warning: "HTTP request status  Fails" this means your drupal/LAMP stack is unable to use DNS to callback to itself. In my case I used my machines's IP to access my Drupal instance. So, rather that use "localhost" use your machine's IP address (you can use ipconfig on MSWin or ifconfig on Mac/Linux) and use that for finishing the twitter account setup process.

Again, not

```
http://localhost/drupal-7.19/twitter/oauth
```

but

```
http://10.0.1.9/drupal-7.19/twitter/oauth
```

(substituting your machine's IP address)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error which i fixed by adding appropriate proxy server details.

`Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in Twitter->request() (line 131 of C:\wamp\www\test_twitter\sites\all\modules\twitter\twitter.lib.php`

The problem was due to proxy-settings. I added values for `$conf['proxy_server']` and `$conf['proxy_port']` in **settings.php** and this error vanished.

I also verified that if i remove the proxy settings, this error is reproduced again.

Answer (score 0):

Install oauth_common and twitter on your Drupal site

Check that both Oauth and the Twitter modules are enabled. I didn't use any of the other Twitter modules to do this

Go to the twitter module in Drupal

Go to the Configure (button) -> settings (Tab)
    (note that the Callback URL is `http://localhost/yourwebsite/twitter/oauth` i.e. *it doesn’t have to be 127.0.0.1*)

Click on the link that says register your application

Go to twitter and sign in to be a developer

Add a new application, making a distinct feed name

Enter your site details 
For localhost use: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/twitter/oauth` for **both** the website and callback URLs
Press save when you've done

Next go to the Test OAuth button - **this will give you your illusive consumer key and consumer secret key**

Back to the Drupal website and and to the twitter module to configure (button) -> settings (Tab)

Copy and paste these consumer and consumer secret keys you just got

Press Save configuration

Hopefully no errors.

Go to the twitter tab in the module and hopefully your twitter avatar has appeared

Read the top of the page where it says "Tweets are pulled from Twitter by running cron. You can view the full list of tweets at the Tweets view."

Select the View Tweets checkbox and click view - Chances are your tweets won’t show up in the next window - yet

Go to your drupal Configuration screen and to [System] Cron and press the "Run cron"

Now go back to view tweets from the twitter module and they should all appear

[This was a pig to figure out]